# passing parameter between component with services in angular:

Tags: angular

I am trying to show logged user in the header navbar after a successful login but for some reason it refuses to appear in the navbar.

```
app.component.ts(as first component)  ->  db-srv-conn.service.ts(as service) -> main.component.ts(as destination component)
```

**db-srv-conn.service.ts :**

```
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
    
    export class DbSrvConnService {
       private bsubject=new BehaviorSubject<any>("t");
       constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
     
  sendMassage(massage: string) {
               this.bsubject.next(massage);
       }


   getMassage(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
       }
    }
```

**app.component.ts(sender component):**

```
import { DbSrvConnService } from 'src/app/sevices/db-srv-conn.service';

export class AppComponent{
  constructor(private DbSrvConnService:DbSrvConnService) { }
...
login(){
    const massage=this.formGroupLogin.value.massage;  
    if (status==1){
            this.DbSrvConnService.send_user(massage);
          }
}
```

**main.component.ts(reciver component):**

```
    import { DbSrvConnService } from 'src/app/sevices/db-srv-conn.service';
    ...
    
   massages: any;
  subscription: Subscription;

      constructor(private DbSrvConnService:DbSrvConnService) { 
        this.subscription = this.DbSrvConnService.getMessage().subscribe(massage => {
          console.log(massage);
          
        });
```

but,No value is displayed for the massage,please help me.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz working sample?

Comment: No there is no need to registration. just paste your code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hello-world and then click on `Fork` button then send the link

Comment: There is a lot of code in the components and it is not possible to implement them in stackblitz

Comment: I mean a small piece of code to show the problem not all your code

Comment: Is the receiver component a child of app.component?

Comment: no , i have a login page that want to send username from login page to menu page

Comment: While you navigate to that page right? I just want to make sure that the receiver page is loaded so that it can receive the subscription

Comment: Also, in app.component.ts shouldn't it be 
`this.DbSrvConnService.sendMassage(massage); `  and not `this.DbSrvConnService.send_user(massage);`

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps, i think the typos are causing this issue.

1. In db-srv-conn.service.ts: , replace the `return this.subject.asObservable();` to

```
getMassage(): Observable<any> {
     return this.bsubject.asObservable();
    }
```

2. In app.component.ts, replace `this.DbSrvConnService.send_user(massage);`  to the following

```
login(){
   const massage=this.formGroupLogin.value.massage;  
   if (status==1){
           this.DbSrvConnService.sendMassage(massage);
         }
   // navigation or whatever down here

}
```